For virtual threads, how to control the number of platform threads via Spring
I need to use virtual threads through SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor and I have the following three questions:

How do I control the number of platform threads used to dispatch the virtual threads?
By setting taskTerminationTimeout is it possible to kill threads when they are blocking, and can this solve the thread pinned problem?
How to get information about the ForkJoinPool, which can be used to monitor the health of the virtual threads.

I looked up some information and didn't find a way


You don't, 2. No, 3. uses spring boot which includes metrics.


Regarding the third point, some implementation details can be provided

You won't need to implement anything. Also virtual threads don't have health as they are gone as soon as the task they are assigned has finished.

The intention is to warn Thread Pinned by monitoring the forkjoinpool.

With Reflection you can get an access to FJP instance, used for virtual threads. But it won't give you much. Virtual thread pinning can be traced by Flight Recorder, FJP has little to nothing to do with pinning and itself is hardly aware of VTs. VT health is quite wide of a topic, but currently Flight Recorder provides rather narrow scope of VTs.

As for controlling number of platform threads used to dispatch the virtual threads you can control few things like FJP parallelism with system properties.
